# how to center menu text on (border-bottom)

Tags: html, css

How can I center menu text on (`border-bottom`) with this code

Please help me correct the below html/css code

**CSS** & **HTML**

```css
#main-menu {

width:all;
height:60px;
background-color:#555;
}

#main-menu a {
   text-indent: 85px;
   padding:15px; 
   position: relative;
   text-decoration:none;
   color:#fff;
   line-height: center;
   float:right;
   margin:center;
   left: -180px;
   display: inline-block;
   display: table-cell;
   text-align:center; 
   outline-width: center;
}

#main-menu a:hover {
color: #ffa500;
border-bottom:2px solid #ffa500; 
}
```

```html
 
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
    <title>Hi</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="main-menu">

          <a href="#">Home</a>
          <a href="#">Blog</a>
          <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
          <a href="#">login</a>
          <a href="#">call us</a>
          <a href="#">vip</a>

    </div> 
    </div>
    </div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

thanks...

Comment: so many css errors. but for now just remove `text-indent: 85px;` and work with `margin` and `padding`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasnt sure what the issue was so I just restyled the nav for you, here

https://jsfiddle.net/dsvy5exv/17/

```
  #main-menu {

      width:100%;
      background-color:#555;
  }

  #main-menu a{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

also keep in mind that its harder to override IDs. You can use them but it might be better to use classes in the place of IDs, unless you have specific reason to use them.

Answer (score 0):

use following css code

```
#main-menu a{
color: #fff;
display: table-cell;
float: right;
left: -180px;
padding: 15px 25px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#main-menu {
    height: 60px;
    display: table;
    background-color: #555;
    width: 100%;
}

#main-menu a {
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation how this solves the asker's problem.

Comment: He already did I just modified with parent set table property and removed some properties in child

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

**CSS**

```
.main-menu {
   width:100%;
   height:60px;
   background-color:#555;
}

.main-menu a {
  padding:15px; 
  position: relative;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:center; 
  outline-width: center;
  border:1px solid #000;
  margin-right:-4px;
  margin-top:10px;
}
.main-menu a:hover:before {
   width:100%;
   left:0;
   position:absolute;
   background:#fa0;
   height:2px;
   bottom:0;
   content:'';
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="main-menu">

  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Blog</a>
  <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
  <a href="#">login</a>
  <a href="#">call us</a>
  <a href="#">vip</a>

</div>
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/torz9epa/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
#main-menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}
a { 
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
}

 a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
    color: #ffa500;
    border-bottom:2px solid #ffa500; 
}

.active:hover {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: #ffa500;
    border-bottom:2px solid #ffa500; 
}
,____________________________________html___________________________________,
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main-menu">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">Blog</a>
            <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
            <a href="#">login</a>
            <a href="#">call us</a>
            <a href="#">vip</a>
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```